# How to test URL path ( Last Folder ) + Number of characters

Tags: javascript

How to test URL path (last folder)

**URL path :**

```
http://www.example.com/#/aaaaaaaaa
```

**Number of characters : aaaaaaaaa**

```
9
```

**Html code :**

```
<html>
<body>

<script>

var zz = "http://www.example.com/#/aaaaaaaaa";
if (!$.trim(zz)){   
alert("no");
}
else{ 
alert("ok");
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**I want like this :**

```
http://www.example.com/#/aaaaaaaaa :(9 chars) alert("ok")
http://www.example.com/#/ : alert("no");
http://www.example.com : alert("no");
http://www.example.com/#/aa : alert("no")
http://www.example.com/#/aaaaaaaaaaaaaa : alert("no")
```

Comment: SO is not the place to request a job to be done what have you tried?

Comment: Use a regex, or just String.split if that suffices, to retrieve the last part of the URL, then just get the length of that string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#/aaaa` is a **hash**, not folder. You can find it in `window.location.hash`

```
if(window.location.hash && window.location.hash.replace("#/", "").length == 9){                                                                                  
   alert("ok")                                                                                                                                                     
}else{                                                                                                                                                            
   alert("no")                                                                                                                                                     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
var zz = "http://www.example.com/#/aaaaaaaaa";
  var url= zz.split('/#/');
  if(url[1] && url[1].length==9)
  {
  alert('ok')
  }
  else {
     alert('no');
  }
```